# При добавлении следующих функций, все работает некорректно. Возможно как-то исправить?

Tags: javascript, javascript-events, domdocument

https://codepen.io/yasakova/pen/qBopvod

```
        let parent = document.querySelector('.btn');
        restartBtn = document.createElement('button');
        restartBtn.className.add = 'btn-restart';
        restartBtn.textContent = 'Начать новую игру';
        parent.appendChild(restartBtn);
        restartBtn.style.fontSize = '16px'
        restartBtn.style.display = 'flex';
        restartBtn.style.padding = '8px';
       
    
    
    restartBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        win_block.style.display = 'none';
        guesses.innerHTML = '';
        textarea.value = '';
        attempts = 0;
        NUMBER = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        console.log(NUMBER);
        restartBtn.style.display = 'none';
    })
```

Comment: addEventListener находится вне функии

Comment: Зачем вы каждый раз кнопку рестарта создаете? Вы или удаляйте её каждый раз при перезапуске, или сделайте сразу и скрывайте.

Comment: все изменения ничего не исправили

Answer (score 0):

Лучше создайте кнопку в начале с помощью вашей же функции `create_btn_Reset`, которая вернет вам уже готовый `HTMLButtonElement` с добавленым обработчиком клика.

```
/**
* Функции все таки лучше называть без подчеркиваний createBtnReset()
* И лучше определитесь у вас рестарт или ресет, будет меньше путанницы
*/
const restartBtn = create_btn_Reset();

function create_btn_Reset() {
  const parent = document.querySelector('.btn');
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.className.add('btn-restart');
  button.textContent = 'Начать новую игру';
  /** Все, что в обработчике лучше разделить на функции поменьше */
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) => {
    win_block.style.display = 'none';
    guesses.innerHTML = '';
    textarea.value = '';
    attempts = 0;
    NUMBER = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    console.log(NUMBER);
    this.style.display = 'none';
  });
  return button; // пускай функция вернет уже собранную кнопку
};
```

Советую почитать [советы по стилю кода](https://learn.javascript.ru/coding-style).

Объявлять большое кол-во переменных в глобале - не очень хорошая практика. В вашей игре очень просто читерить, обращаясь к переменным из консоли.

```js
console.log(NUMBER);
```

Я могу накрутить себе сколько угодно кол-во попыток:

```
attempts = 500 // станет 500 попыток
```

Оберните все в анонимную функцию [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/IIFE), чтобы закрыть эту уязвимость.

```js
(() => {
 // код игры
})();
```

В коде много повторений, некоторые функции включают в себя код из других функций. Старайтесь придерживаться принципа единственной обязанности, разделите код на функции поменьше, которые будут выполнять что-то одно.

Можете почитать про [SOLID](https://web-creator.ru/articles/solid), [DRY](https://web-creator.ru/articles/dry)

Выводить текст "вы победили", проверяя стили блока в цикле `while` - это точно не то, что вам нужно.

```js
while (win_block.style.display = 'flex') { // так не делают, этот цикл может никогда не выполниться, страница будет подвисать
    restartBtn.style.position = 'absolute';
    restartBtn.style.marginTop = '15em';
}
```

Вот так добавлять стили - дело очень неблагодарное. Лучше перенесите их в css и добавте вместе с классом `btn-restart`.

```
       // restartBtn.className.add = 'btn-restart';
        restartBtn.className.add('btn-restart');
        restartBtn.textContent = 'Начать новую игру';
        parent.appendChild(restartBtn);
        restartBtn.style.fontSize = '16px' // перенесите в css
        restartBtn.style.display = 'flex'; // перенесите в css
        restartBtn.style.padding = '8px'; // перенесите в css
```

Бонусом можете посмотреть, как я написал вашу игру в объектно-ориентированном стиле.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/neverm1ndo/pen/ExELEdd?editors=1011)